Ошибка UnboundLocalError at /news/create cannot access local variable 'error' where it is not associated with a value (Django)
Что не так в коде?
views:

def create(request):
if request.method == 'post':
    form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        error = 'Форма была неверной'


form = ArticlesForm()
data = {
    'form': form,
    'error': error
}
return render(request, 'news/create.html', data)


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // Ошибка UnboundLocalError возникает, когда переменная используется до того, как ей присвоено значение. В вашем коде ошибка связана с переменной error, которая может использоваться до того, как ей присвоено значение и/или не инициализирована -> используйте Debug, чтоб просматривать значение переменных

Значит код доходит до строчки 'error': error минуя строчку error = 'Форма была неверной'. Такое возможно если вызывается не POST-запрос, а, например, GET.
Как вариант решения можно объявить переменную в самом начале с значением по-умолчанию
def create(request):
    error = None
    # ...остальной код

